# Cannot show the updated image in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I use Raspberry pi to get image and send the captured image to google drive. Using the same id in google drive, I will keep update the image and send a link to flutter (firebase). `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=`. But my flutter app just can show the first image and cannot get the updated image although updated image has been sent to the google drive. I got try use the link to search online and can get the updated image. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much without seeing your code, my best guest is you call this request just once when app start then waiting it changes automatically when the source change but it can't. There is two ways to do that, first you can uhm simple refresh with a time setting to check source and everytime it checked image should change, second and probably more suitable way could be [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) but if you use same name or id with new image and old image I can't tell it works without trying.

Edit: Just came to my mind, if you are using Image.network try to use [NetworkImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) class instead of it.